# How to set dotted line in Jpgraph with php

Tags: php, apache, jpgraph

I want to set dotted line in jpgraph with php, but for this moment I set only standart line with this code:

```
  $lineplot2 = new LinePlot($pro1, $pro1X);
  $lineplot2->SetStyle("solid");
  $lineplot2->SetWeight(3);
  $lineplot2->SetColor('red');
```

Can I get example how to set dotted or broken line .. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$lineplot2->SetStyle("dotted");`

https://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/classref/LineProperty.html